# How to remove a div node with the backspace key in a contentedible div, in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, contenteditable

I have this HTML code :

```html
<div contenteditable id=txt>
    <div class=b id=block1></div>Text <span class=c id=comment1Start></span>1<span class=c id=comment1End></span>.
    <div class=b id=block2></div>Text 2.
</div>
```

When I place the caret just after a closed `<div>` tag and I press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to remove a `<div>` node, nothing is happening in Firefox. Why ?

Empty nodes serve as markers and they have a CSS style. The markers are added to the text with JavaScript.

`<span>` nodes are removed.

Comment: Seems to works for me. If I place the cursor after the first line, and keep backspacing, the span is removed. Content Editable is a huge pain to get working consistently between browsers though.

Comment: At least in my testing (FF48.0.2), the `<span>` elements are removed (looking at DOM changes) when you hit backspace after positioning the cursor (note that the cursor does not move upon this removal of the `<span>`). This is different from what happens if the cursor arrives in the position from having hit the Backspace key. In such cases, the text is removed, but the `<div>` and `<span>` elements remain.

Comment: @kthornbloom and @Makyen : Indeed, the `<span>` is removed (sorry) but not `<div>`, on FF48.0.2.

Comment: I haven't looked too hard for one. But, is there a spec that defines what is supposed to happen? In Chrome: the `<span>` elements are removed when any adjacent character is removed. The first `<div>` is never removed. The second `<div>` is sometimes removed sometimes not depending on how the cursor gets to be adjacent to it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide unique `id` values for every single element.  This will facilitate discussion of each element.

Comment: @Makyen : It's done. Thank you.